# Mv all files to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, ubuntu-16.04, mv

I accidentally moved all files from the directory to the Dropbox folder:

```
mv * ~/Dropbox/
```

That was not my intention at all. Now, Dropbox informed me that 1200 new files were uploaded, but I can't see them. Also `locate` doesn't find them either. What happened? Why don't they appear?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Dropbox widget as shown at desktop top status bar ... get into the show recent picklist and pick a file ... it should take you to that file's new  location ... did this work ?

Alternatively poke about in your https://www.dropbox.com/  to see if your files appear there

The nuclear option is to issue a find on all your files then grep its output

```
sudo -i   #  login as root to enable viewing all files
find  / | grep known_filename_which_is_missing
```

Assure you where logged on as yourself when you issued the mv command ? and not root or another userid  ?

Also issue this to view your files ... in case they begin with a dot

```
cd ~/Dropbox/
ls -la
```

and not just a   `ls`

When you view your account from a browser is your Dropbox usage noticeably  higher than normal ?  is it at 100% ?

Comment: No, just myself. I checked Dropbox-nothing. Also tmp dir doesn't seem to contain anythin

Comment: could it be that there are too many files exceeding the allocated space? What happens in this case?

Comment: No it's actually just 3%...really weird